# Is there any way to retrieve only the scheduled task name using SchTasks command?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

Iam working on windows7 . I have scheduled list of tasks using windows task scheduler, the tasks was scheduled successfully.

Now I want to retrieve only the tasks scheduled using SchTasks command instead of status,Next Run Time .....

So is there any command to get only those scheduled tasks?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Does `schtasks /query /fo LIST /v | findstr "Taskname"` help?

Comment: I need list of task names here. how could i specify "TaskName" particularly

Comment: That command gives you a list of all scheduled task names. Have you run it?