# How to extract the scheduling information for scheduled tasks from task scheduler

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I need to get the list of all tasks along with their name, their execution command and most importantly their trigger time/repeatation time from windows task scheduler.
Can someone please help with some easier steps instead of writing them manually?

Comment: Surely you’ve discovered `schtasks` and Powershell’s `Get-ScheduledTask`. What have you tried?

Comment: The comments on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1195993/is-there-any-way-to-retrieve-only-the-scheduled-task-name-using-schtasks-command) might get you started.